# Using [Authorize] without SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, simplemembership

Is there a way to use...

```
[Authorize(Roles: "Administrator")]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

...with my own `Roles` database table, without using `SimpleMembershipProvider`?

My `Users` and `Roles` model classes:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class UserModel
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual RoleModel Role { get; set; }
}

[Table("Roles")]
public class RoleModel
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Does someone have the same problem?

Comment: The Authorize Attribute is indipendent from the MembershipProvider - perhaps you should take a look into the new ASP.NET Identity Model.

Comment: But how do I tell it to check for roles in my database and not into the default one?

Comment: For ASP.NET Identity you just have to implement the Store and fullfill the Interfaces of IRole.

Comment: You should read my question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470423/using-asp-net-identity-for-a-role-provider-easily. I just went through this about a week ago.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own `Authorize` attribute by inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute` class

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

}
```

Then you can configure it however you like.

Also you can take a look at these questions on Stackoverflow:

1. [Custom Authorize Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070339/custom-authorize-attribute)
2. [ASP.NET MVC 4 Custom Authorize Attribute with Permission Codes (without roles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264496/asp-net-mvc-4-custom-authorize-attribute-with-permission-codes-without-roles)

Comment: When the code inside it is _run_ or _checked_? Is there an injection of code wherever is the attribute placed?

Comment: There are some methods that you can override like [`OnAuthorization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.onauthorization(v=vs.118).aspx).take a look at [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute_methods(v=vs.118).aspx) methods

Comment: I don't even know of how to write the code to check for specifics roles into my database from inside the `AuthorizeAttribute`, can you help me please? I've never worked hooking framework methods before.

Comment: An alternative to writing a custom AuthorizeAttribute is to create a custom membership provider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.100).aspx . You then configure your app to use your membership provider and the AuthorizeAttribute will work as is.

Comment: @Selman22 - You seem to be confusing Membership with Roles... They are two different things.  You don't need to write a custom authorize attribute, nor a custom membership provider.  You may need to write a custom role provider.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and I used a custom attribute. But my roles weren't as sophisticated. I needed to be able to give multiple roles to a user so I just used a string collection to do that. I used this custom filter

```
CustomAuthorize(UserRole="AUTHORIZED_ROLE");
```

---

```
 public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string UserRole { get; set; }
        protected IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork();
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            if (!isAuthorized)
            {
                return false;
            }
            var currentUser;//Get Current User 
            if(UserRole==currentUser.Role.Name)
            {
                return true;
            }


        return false;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary(
                        new
                        {//redirect where you want to in case of not authorized.
                            controller = "Home",
                            action = "AccessDenied" 
                        })
                    );
    }
```