# Accessing HttpContext and User Identity from data layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, httpcontext

I need to implement AddedBy/ChangedBy type fields on my Base Entity that all other entities inherit from ( Fluent Nhibernate ).

Accessing `HttpContext.User.Identity` from within my Repository/Data layer is probably not a good idea.. or is it ? 
What's the best way to grab my user ( current identity ) information to record who the records were added or changed by ? 
Re-factoring the entire application to include user information in repository calls would be silly. I'm sure there is a better, more generic way.

Comment: Sounds like you will run into a circular dependency if you try accessing the UserManager from your data layer.  Going the long road and filling out the By property with every create/update is going to be the best bet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Access the HttpContext from the Data Layer makes the life harder, specially if you use Unit Tests. The solution is to create a service to provide application wide user information, something like:

```
public interface ICurrentUserService {
   string UserName {get;}
   string UserId {get;}
   string HostIP {get;}
   // etc.
}
```

Then you can implement the concrete service and inject it using your
preferred IoC container.

```
public class CurrentWebUserService : ICurrentUserService {
    // implement interface members 
    public CurrentWebUserService(HttpContext context) { ... }

    public string UserName { get { ... } } 
    // etc.
}

// maybe you want a stub service to inject while unit testing.
public class CurrentUserServiceStub : ICurrentUserService {

}

// data layer
public class MyDaoService {
    public DaoService(ICurrentUserService currentUser) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I've been trying and have problems putting this all together: 1) Create an interface/class in my Web project with needed user properties.
2) Access these properties from the data layer
At what point does the class get injected with data though?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. Referencing your `HttpContext.User.Identity` class from within your repository is not a good idea. The `HttpContext` is a UI concern and as such, should go no further than the UI layer.

What you should be doing is harnessing an IoC container (such as StructureMap) to inject your dependency (`HttpContext.User.Identity`) details into your repository, or any other layer such as the service layer via dependency injection.

For an example of how this can be setup (in this instance it's the session object) see the latter part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20703040/963542).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this suggests using sessions even with dependency injection ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You should always be aiming to program to an interface, not implementation. So instead of directly programming against your `HttpContext.Current.Session` object (or in your case `HttpContext.User.Identity`), instead you program against an abstraction of it that is built up in your application's [composite root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). That when changes such as ASP.NET MVC 5 come out where they've change the `HttpContext` object you have to change it in a single place rather than throughout your application.

Answer (score 1):

HttpContext.Current is a static member that you can access anywhere in the application.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Obviously there are problems, such as if you don't HAVE an HttpContext when the code is called.

So HttpContext.Current.User should work for you.  I wouldn't recommend it, because your underlying data access code is now depending on stuff that should be kept to your display or controller logic, etc.  Also, this assumes that your data access is in the web application itself and not part of, say, an external library.

Personally, I'd just pass in the salient details, like user ID and access time, as part of the add and modify database calls. Make an "AuditTrail" class or something.  That would let you reuse that data access code (always a good thing) in another project without having to pull out all the HttpContext stuff.

Comment: Passing user credential in all repositories means doing a lot of code re factoring. I'm looking into IoC container solution that others suggested for now that I don't know much about yet.

Comment: Yeah, it does involve a lot of refactoring, though that happens when the spec changes during development.  IoC is not something I know a lot about.  Hopefully you won't have to rewrite everything anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The AddedBy/ChangedBy field is potentially important in any data backend. You may even want to have AccessedBy for logging purposes. Therefore, you would want to think that the user information is a central part of your data. It is also possible that you may want other details such as the client's IP address logged for security reasons. Probably a good idea to have the entire context rippled down to the data layer so that you have the flexibility to capture and save the client information.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but you didn't answer the question how and whats the best way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used a factory to get the correct repo with or without a "CurrentUser" since sometimes you need to know who the user is and sometimes you don't.

```
//I have a current user that I got from the Identity
var repo = RepoFactory.GetRepo<Users>(currentUserId);

//I don't have a current user
var repo = RepoFactory.GetRepo<Users>()
```

This way you can pull the Identity from the HttpContext and pass only details you need to the repo.

Comment: Interesting solution but it would cause a lot of code refactoring on my end.

Answer (score 0):

1. `HttpContext.User.Identity` is of `System.Security.Principal.IIdentity` type. Don't mess it up with **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity** library (NuGet package) which is actually pointed by asp.net-identity tag in your question.
2. Identity lib consists of common part and its ORM implementation. Typically it is for **Entity Framework**. But if you're going to use `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` package in the way you describe with NHibernate, then you most likely will need [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/).

I didn't use it, but I used EF implementation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460704/454869) how to inherit of predefined `IdentityDbContext<T>` where T is your User class. I guess, NH has similar fluent configuration. Then you can link any of entities in your `DbContext` to `AppUser`