# The 'GetUriByAction' method in the LinkGenerator class in Asp.Net Core is not defined in the Repository layer of the project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

## The EmployeeLinks class in the Repository layer.

```
using Contracts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Entities.LinkModels;
using Entities.Models;
using Shared.DataTransferObjects;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Repository.Extensions.Utility
{
    public class EmployeeLinks : IEmployeeLinks
    {
        private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;
        private readonly IDataShaper<EmployeeDto> _dataShaper;

        public EmployeeLinks(LinkGenerator linkGenerator, IDataShaper<EmployeeDto> dataShaper)
        {
            _linkGenerator = linkGenerator;
            _dataShaper = dataShaper;
        }

        public LinkResponse TryGenerateLinks(IEnumerable<EmployeeDto> employeesDto, string fields, Guid companyId, HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var shapedEmployees = ShapeData(employeesDto, fields);
            if (ShouldGenerateLinks(httpContext))
                return ReturnLinkdedEmployees(employeesDto, fields, companyId, httpContext, shapedEmployees);

            return ReturnShapedEmployees(shapedEmployees);
        }
        private List<Entity> ShapeData(IEnumerable<EmployeeDto> employeesDto, string fields) =>
             _dataShaper.ShapeData(employeesDto, fields)
             .Select(e => e.Entity)
             .ToList();

        private bool ShouldGenerateLinks(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var mediaType = (MediaTypeHeaderValue)httpContext.Items["AcceptHeaderMediaType"];
            return mediaType.SubTypeWithoutSuffix.EndsWith("hateoas", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        private LinkResponse ReturnShapedEmployees(List<Entity> shapedEmployees) =>
         new LinkResponse { ShapedEntities = shapedEmployees };

        private LinkResponse ReturnLinkdedEmployees(IEnumerable<EmployeeDto> employeeDto, string fields, Guid companyId,
            HttpContext httpContext, List<Entity> shapedEmployees)
        {
            var employeeDtoList = employeeDto.ToList();

            for(var index = 0; index < shapedEmployees.Count; index++)
            {
                var employeeLinks = CreateLinksForEmployee(httpContext, companyId, employeeDtoList[index].Id, fields);
                shapedEmployees[index].Add("Links", employeeLinks);
            }

            var employeeCollection = new LinkCollectionWrapper<Entity>(shapedEmployees);
            var linkedEmployees = CreateLinksForEmployees(httpContext, employeeCollection);

            return new LinkResponse { HasLinks = true, LinkedEntities = linkedEmployees };
        }

        private List<Link> CreateLinksForEmployee(HttpContext httpContext, Guid companyId, Guid id, string fields = "")
        {
            var links = new List<Link>
            {
                new Link(_linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(httpContext, "GetEmployeeForCompany", "Employees", values: new {companyId, id, fields}),
                    "self",
                    "GET"),
                new Link(_linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(httpContext,"DeleteEmployeeForCompany", "Employees", values: new { companyId, id }),
                    "delete_employee",
                    "DELETE"),
                new Link(_linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(httpContext, "UpdateEmployeeForCompany", "Employees", values: new { companyId, id }),
                    "update_employee",
                    "PUT"),
                new Link(_linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(httpContext, "PartiallyUpdateEmployeeForCompany", "Employees", values: new { companyId, id }),
                    "partially_update_employee",
                    "PATCH")
            };
            return links;
        }

        private LinkCollectionWrapper<Entity> CreateLinksForEmployees(HttpContext httpContext, LinkCollectionWrapper<Entity> employeesWrapper)
        {
            employeesWrapper.Links.Add(new Link(_linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(httpContext, "GetEmployeesForCompany", values: new { }),
            "self",
            "GET"));
            return employeesWrapper;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try LinkGenerator class in Presentation layer i.e. Controller, 'GetUriByAction' works without any exception. But it doesn't work in EmployeeLinks class in Repository layer. It shows the following error:
'LinkGenerator' does not contain a definition for 'GetUriByAction' and no accessible extension method 'GetUriByAction' accepting a first argument of type 'LinkGenerator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Link generator is part of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref` , but you won't be able to install it in your Repository project.

Instead modify your Repository `.csproj` file and add:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source of `GetUriByAction`, we can see that `HttpContext` is necessary for this method, while `HttpContext` is not able to be accessed directly in Repository layer. That's the reason you got this error. In the meanwhile, this looks not to be a good idea to access Httpcontext in the Repository layer based on this design. I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708441/accessing-httpcontext-and-user-identity-from-data-layer) which had the same idea.

```
public static string? GetUriByAction(
    this LinkGenerator generator,
    HttpContext httpContext,
    string? action = default,
    string? controller = default,
    object? values = default,
    string? scheme = default,
    HostString? host = default,
    PathString? pathBase = default,
    FragmentString fragment = default,
    LinkOptions? options = default)
```

If we want to do what you want to achieve, then we need to get HttpContext there, `IHttpContextAccessor` should be the answer. [Related document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0#access-httpcontext-from-custom-components). Let's add the service in Program.cs `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`, and then inject it into the Repository layer, then use `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` as the method parameter.

[image]